# CSV reading in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I wrote that code for csv reading, but right now I have this problem:

> ValueError: invalid literal for float():
>   4.000E+00;3.125E-07;-7.854E-13

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def read_datafile(file_name):
    data = np.loadtxt(file_name, delimiter=' ')
    return data

for r in range(0,25,1):
    data = read_datafile("S:\Dok\Python\Data\Codes\Model2\Mod{}.csv".format(r))

    x = data[:,0]
    y = data[:,1]
    z = data[:,2]

    degree = u"\u00b0"

    fig = plt.figure(1)
    plt.title("Model {}".format(r) + degree)
    plt.plot(x, abs(y + 1j * z), color='k')
    plt.show()
```

My files look like this:

[image]

Comment: What this line  `x = data[:,0]` should do? You can't access values from a iterable this way

Comment: @SiHa You are right, I have change `delimiter=';'` and it worked. Please write it as an answer, so I can mark it. Thank you btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `np.loadtxt(file_name, delimiter=' ')`, but according to your error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 4.000E+00;3.125E-07;-7.854E-13,
```

... it is semicolon-delimited.

Because of this, you are getting the whole line in at once, and to the conversion fails. If you change to `delimiter=';'`, it should work.